# Finding $2\pi\int_0^a \cosh(y) \sinh(1.85) $.

Tags: calculus, geometry, definite-integrals

My function is $ x = \cosh(y)$ from $0 < y < a$ and to be rotated around the $y$-axis, where $a$ describes how big the object will be. (The object is said to be a vase.) The vase is to have a flat bottom.

We are given that the arc length is $\sinh(1.85)$ for the constant $a$. How big is the surface area of the vase?

---

My problem lies with the constant $a$.

The standard formula for surface area is:

$$2\pi\int_a^b x ds $$

and this should result to:

$$2\pi\int_0^a \cosh(y) \sinh(1.85) $$

but I can't calculate this integral without knowing the constant $a$ and I have no idea how to do that.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a parameterized curve $\left\{ {\left( {\cosh y,y} \right):y \in \left\langle {0,a} \right\rangle } \right\}$ and want to know its length.

We have $\sinh \left( {1.85} \right) = \int_0^a {\sqrt {{{\left( {\frac{d}{{dy}}\cosh y} \right)}^2} + {{\left( {\frac{d}{{dy}}y} \right)}^2}} dy}  = \int_0^a {\sqrt {{{\sinh }^2}y + 1} dy}  = \int_0^a {\cosh ydy}  = \sinh a \Rightarrow a = 1.85$

Identities used: ${\left( {\cosh x} \right)^\prime } = \sinh x$, ${\left( {\sinh x} \right)^\prime } = \cosh x$, ${\cosh ^2}x - {\sinh ^2}x = 1$, [length of parametricaly defined curve](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length#Finding_arc_lengths_by_integrating) (the line "If a curve is defined parametricaly...")

Comment: Tried to use $a$ = 1.85, but wrong answer :(

I'm completely lost as how to answer this assignment.

Comment: Sorry, but that is the value of $a$, you should check the other steps in your solution